# Split up json-data fetched with axios in to a clickable list-item that redirects to page

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, axios

Noob to react and everything that has to do with web-developing pretty much. I'm trying to create a list in a Navbar with buttons that redirects the user to a new page. I'm fetching sports from a JSON-file and I have the code below to reduce/get rid of all the duplicates. My question now is what the best practice to create a list in, e.g. a navbar with a button that gets one sport each. I have a total of 5 sports in {postList} and I have no Idea how to split them up from the SportList.js-file. My goal is attaching them to an icon somehow (like a football for football), that sends the user to the football-page (where you can see all the football games). Not really sure where to start.

I hope my question is not to confusing, english is not my first language. Any help and/or hints is awesome. Ask me if it doesn't make sense and I will try to rephrase the question. Thank you!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class SportList extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://data.json')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          posts: res.data
        });
      })
  }
  render() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    const uniquePosts = Object.values(posts.reduce((r,c) => { 
      r[c.sport] = c 
      return r
    }, {}))
    const postList = uniquePosts.length ? (
        uniquePosts.map(post => {
          return (
            <div key={post.id}>
              <div>
                {post.sport}
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
      ) : (<div>No Sports Available</div>)
    return (<div>{postList}</div>);
  }
}

export default SportList
```

Comment: so each tab should be each components and it should route it like if your site name is https://www.example.com, once you click on the football tab it should be https://www.example.com/football. Is that what you are looking for

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Yeah, something like that. I think I have some knowledge, but not much, about the redirecting with routing and so on. My biggest problem is how to get each sport from the {postList} (which took me forever to remove the duplicates with a little help from stackoverflow.).

Comment: you need to use React Router package, so basically once you get the api, you need to create a Route component which consist of the path and component. Can you post the json. So i can try it and post it

Comment: are you using redux in the project, or using the state of the component only.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Not using Redux, but I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install two packages react-router-dom and lodash.

After the api call , once you get the data. Get the sport names, create each components for the sport. Pass the data to each component.

**Note**: **Since i don't have the api, i have used to get it from a file, so you can call the api in the componentDidMount and set the data to state.**

Also use the Route component inorder to render the data based on each component load.

I hope this will solve the issue. Please let me know if any issue occurred.

```js
// App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Aux from './Aux';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Data from './Data';
import FootBall from './FootBall';
import EachNavLink from './EachNavLink';
import {groupBy} from 'lodash'

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    apiData: Data
  }

  getData = (sport) => {
    let data = groupBy(this.state.apiData, "sport")
    return data[sport];
  }

  renderTabs = () => {
    const { apiData } = this.state
    const sports = Array.from(new Set(apiData.map(o => o.sport)))

    const tabs = sports.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <EachNavLink
          key={index}
          href={`/${item}`}
          name={item}
        />
      )
    })
    return tabs
  }


  render() {
    const { apiData } = this.state
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Aux>
          <Aux>
            {
              apiData.length > 0 ?
                this.renderTabs()
                :
                <p>Data is Loading... Please wait.</p>
            }
          </Aux>
          <div className="content">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/FOOTBALL" render={(routeProps) => (<FootBall {...routeProps} data={apiData.length > 0 ? this.getData("FOOTBALL") : []} />)} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Aux>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}



export default App;


// Data.js

const data = [
    {
        "awayName": "Panthrakikos Komotini",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.228Z",
        "group": "Greek Cup",
        "homeName": "Chania FC",
        "id": 1002916450,
        "name": "Chania FC - Panthrakikos Komotini",
        "objectId": "1UaQjc7lIb",
        "sport": "FOOTBALL",
        "country": "ENGLAND",
        "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "PAOK Thessaloniki",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.234Z",
        "group": "Greek Cup",
        "homeName": "Olympiakos Volos",
        "id": 1002916451,
        "name": "Olympiakos Volos - PAOK Thessaloniki",
        "objectId": "UPJ240T2Qj",
        "sport": "FOOTBALL",
        "country": "FRANCE",
        "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Ukraine U18",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.244Z",
        "group": "Under 18",
        "homeName": "Israel U18",
        "id": 1003022920,
        "name": "Israel U18 - Ukraine U18",
        "objectId": "fZZUhitsVt",
        "sport": "FOOTBALL",
        "country": "SWEDEN",
        "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Stade Gabesien",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.249Z",
        "group": "Ligue 1",
        "homeName": "CA Bizertin",
        "id": 1003015194,
        "name": "CA Bizertin - Stade Gabesien",
        "objectId": "Bf52z7GIut",
        "sport": "FOOTBALL",
        "country": "SWEDEN",
        "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "AS de la Marsa",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.255Z",
        "group": "Ligue 1",
        "homeName": "Club Africain",
        "id": 1003015197,
        "name": "Club Africain - AS de la Marsa",
        "objectId": "sFjPkmljKv",
        "sport": "FOOTBALL",
        "country": "ENGLAND",
        "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Kastamonuspor",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.261Z",
        "group": "T\u00fcrkyie Kupasi",
        "homeName": "Kar\u015f\u0131yaka",
        "id": 1003016331,
        "name": "Kar\u015f\u0131yaka - Kastamonuspor",
        "objectId": "cRqV2RTmsu",
        "sport": "FOOTBALL",
        "country": "FRANCE",
        "state": "FINISHED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Allen, Gareth",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.266Z",
        "group": "German Masters Qualifiers",
        "homeName": "Ding Junhui",
        "id": 1003018193,
        "name": "Ding Junhui - Allen, Gareth",
        "objectId": "nPuz011p0W",
        "sport": "SNOOKER",
        "country": "SWEDEN",
        "state": "NOT_STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Lines, Peter",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.272Z",
        "group": "German Masters Qualifiers",
        "homeName": "Trump, Judd",
        "id": 1003018186,
        "name": "Trump, Judd - Lines, Peter",
        "objectId": "CSJn3kZhdx",
        "sport": "SNOOKER",
        "country": "ENGLAND",
        "state": "NOT_STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "SKIF-Krasnodar",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.278Z",
        "group": "Cup",
        "homeName": "Dinamo Astrakhan",
        "id": 1003027200,
        "name": "Dinamo Astrakhan - SKIF-Krasnodar",
        "objectId": "enCbqOuRLr",
        "sport": "HANDBALL",
        "country": "SWEDEN",
        "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "THK Tver",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.283Z",
        "group": "VHL",
        "homeName": "Zauralie Kurgan",
        "id": 1002988754,
        "name": "Zauralie Kurgan - THK Tver",
        "objectId": "7HWfuCIMlp",
        "sport": "ICE_HOCKEY",
        "country": "ENGLAND",
        "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Doumbia, SReboul, F",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.289Z",
        "group": "Nigeria",
        "homeName": "Harris, L G MMaamoun, K M",
        "id": 1003026313,
        "name": "Harris, L G MMaamoun, K M - Doumbia, SReboul, F",
        "objectId": "JxrZyQKTrw",
        "sport": "TENNIS",
        "country": "FRANCE",
        "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Halebian, Alexios",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.294Z",
        "group": "Dominican Republic",
        "homeName": "Bangoura, Sekou",
        "id": 1003026667,
        "name": "Bangoura, Sekou - Halebian, Alexios",
        "objectId": "tALMRNqAxD",
        "sport": "TENNIS",
        "country": "SWEDEN",
        "state": "NOT_STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Roberts, Justin",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.300Z",
        "group": "Dominican Republic",
        "homeName": "Pla Malfeito, Jaume",
        "id": 1003026666,
        "name": "Pla Malfeito, Jaume - Roberts, Justin",
        "objectId": "KGA9nqYAJl",
        "sport": "TENNIS",
        "country": "ENGLAND",
        "state": "FINISHED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Mridha, J",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.306Z",
        "group": "Qatar",
        "homeName": "Clayton, Scott",
        "id": 1003026476,
        "name": "Clayton, Scott - Mridha, J",
        "objectId": "utc63de1Fl",
        "sport": "TENNIS",
        "country": "FRANCE",
        "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Kania, PKerkhove, L",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.311Z",
        "group": "Ankara",
        "homeName": "Buyukakcay, CKrunic, A",
        "id": 1003026234,
        "name": "Buyukakcay, CKrunic, A - Kania, PKerkhove, L",
        "objectId": "mTVUIuYdbF",
        "sport": "TENNIS",
        "country": "SWEDEN",
        "state": "NOT_STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Chernetsova, DPerper, A",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.317Z",
        "group": "El Kantaoui",
        "homeName": "Baskova, DPodlinska, M",
        "id": 1003026673,
        "name": "Baskova, DPodlinska, M - Chernetsova, DPerper, A",
        "objectId": "heL53W56d2",
        "sport": "TENNIS",
        "country": "FRANCE",
        "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Njoze, M",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.322Z",
        "group": "El Kantaoui",
        "homeName": "Stoilkovska, M",
        "id": 1003026214,
        "name": "Stoilkovska, M - Njoze, M",
        "objectId": "gldlV9xhi2",
        "sport": "TENNIS",
        "country": "SWEDEN",
        "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
        "awayName": "Haas, Barbara",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-18T12:30:39.328Z",
        "group": "Navi Mumbai",
        "homeName": "Jia-Jing Lu",
        "id": 1003026299,
        "name": "Jia-Jing Lu - Haas, Barbara",
        "objectId": "V6Qsm2Wlms",
        "sport": "TENNIS",
        "country": "ENGLAND",
        "state": "FINISHED"
    }
]

export default data


// Aux.js


const aux = ({children}) => children

export default aux

// EachNavLink.js

import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const eachNavLink = ({href,name}) => {
  return(
    <div>
     <NavLink
      to={href}
      activeClassName="active"
     >  
     {name}
     </NavLink>
    </div>
  )
}


export default eachNavLink


// FootBall.js

import React from 'react';

const football = (props) => {
    const { data } = props
    return (
        data.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index}>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Away Name: {item.awayName}</li>
                        <li>Country: {item.country}</li>
                        <li>Group: {item.group}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
}

export default football
```

Comment: Hey! Right now I'm getting 'A <Router> may have only one child element'.

Comment: after the browser router you can wrap the entire thing into a div. Check with that and let me know

Comment: But isn't it in a div already in the code you sent me? Or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: after the <BrowserRouter> there are two divs one div for checking the data and one div with className of contnet. wrap that two div into a single div

Comment: A gotcha. Fixed that, and now I'm getting: 
TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10___default.a.get(...).thern is not a function

Comment: there was a typo in the axios.then .Fixed it added the catch block also. Check now whats the next error ? :) . I have written in the stack snippets. So yeah let me know  hahha :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185120/discussion-between-joel-8-bitar-and-dileep-thomas).

Comment: i have updated the post, just copy the code , i checked in local. Only i added the FootBall you can add the remaining component . Please let me know if you are facing any issue